# How can I make monodevelop render text in KDE?

Tags: linux, slackware, monodevelop

Monodevelop from git in KDE 4.10.2 does not render text in code edit tabs [image: monodevelop run in xterm in kde - no text rendered, no errors]

I tried with xfce and text is rendered ok there.

I tried disabling composition with alt shift f12 and restarting x server but it was no better. 
I also tried disabling font softening in monodevelop options and disabling plugins.
I also tried temporarily deleting my KDE profile.

This is dual screen setup on Nvidia with nouveau. OS is slackware64-current.

Comment: Duplicated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603056/monodevelop-4-0-no-codeview

Comment: i dont think stackoverflow is the right place for this question.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. It looks like this bug still isn't fixed - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316995.

A solution based on the comments of the bug report, which also worked for me, is to set OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK to 1.

So run -

```
OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK=1 monodevelop
```

rather than -

```
monodevelop
```